# MVC in Software development using java swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm developing a software project in `java swing`. I want to follow `MVC` design pattern for better maintainability, portability and reliability. I've looked upon `MVC in Swing` on internet and found some good results like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing)
, [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559194/mvc-pattern-with-java-swing) , [THIS](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html), [THIS](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-swing-mvc-example/), [THIS](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076632/core-java/mvc-meets-swing.html) and few more (**youtube** too) and studied them. Then I built a design architecture for my project based on `MVC` design pattern. Here is the structure which simulate my actual requirements:

[image]

Here is little description about the architecture

> - **Main Controller:** It is responsible to initialize and to start the application. It initialize `MainView` and some other sub-controller like `StudentController`,`TeacherController`. It Contains some methods like `getStudentView()`, `getTeacherView()` which provide viewable components of Student `TAB`, Teacher `TAB` to `MainView`
> - **Main View:** It is the main view which is `JFrame` that contains `JTabbedPane` which uses `MainController#getXXXView()` to display view in its `tabs`. (Here `XXX` can be replaced by `Student`, `Teacher` or any other viewable component which is provided by `Main Controller`
> - **Student Controller:** It controls the `StudentView` and `Student` model and `Student model interface`. It initialize the `Student View` and provides this view to `Main Controller` which is further provide view to `Main View`
> - **Student View:** It is a `JPanel` which contains `JTable` to display the student information and some `JButton` like `add Student, Edit, delete` etc.
> - **Student:** It is Student model class that has `name`, `rollNo` etc fields to store student information.
> - **Student Model Interface:** It is service layer. It takes a `Student` argument and send/add it to `Student Viewable Model` and store into database using `Student Database Model`.
> - **Student Viewable data Model:** It is a `TableModel` that is used to define `JTable` in `Student View`
> - **Student Database Model:** Contains method to store/retrieve student information in/from database
> - **Teacher Controller:** Just like `Student Controller` except it controls the teacher related tasks.
> - **Other Controller:** Represents many `Student Controller` like controllers

**NOTE** `Teacher Controller` and other controllers have same hierarchy as that of `Student Controller`. These controllers access their models and view. For e.g. `Teacher Controller` have `Teacher View`, `Teacher` and `Teacher Model Interface`

**Working of the project**

- Firstly `Main Controller` initialize the `Main View` and all the `sub-controllers` and start the application.
- `Student Controller` implements `ActionListener` and act when there is an event in `Student View`. It is responsible to add, edit, delete student information. It takes information from `Student View`, wrap in `Student` object and pass it to `Model Interface`
- Model interface then pass `Student` Object to `Student Database Model` which store/update/delete the data in database. If it is successful, then `Model Interface` update `Student Viewable data model` which is a `Table Model` that reflects changes in `Student View`

**So my question is whether it is a good design for this kind of application and if it is not, then what should do I do. How can I refine the design for better maintainability, reliability portability. What are some recommendations**

I think its a straight and rigid question but I can't do better.

Comment: First, Swing is already a MVC (albeit a MV-C), trying to wrap another "pure" MVC on the top is going to make your life, complicated.  When you're looking at you design, ask your self the simple question - how easy would it be to remove any one part and replace it with something else?  If you find the answer to be anything other then easy, then your design is wrong

Comment: Why is the `Student` separated from the model?  Technically, a controller managers one view and one model.  Also, why are there two sub `Student` models?  Neither the view nor the controller should care how the model is created, only that it adheres to a specific contract. Also, in more "pure" implementation of MVC, the view and the model should no nothing about each other and all interaction is done through the controller - this part I find hard to swallow, as it means duplicating a bunch of code, where adhering to a prescribed contract/interface would solve the issue :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Student is model class that has simple fields and getter and setter methods. Student view has JTable and it requires TableModel to display the student information. Student view doesn't know about any of these models, but it only accept TableModel as an argument. This Table Model is defined by Student view data model class. I built model interface as if in future i don't want to see student info, then I can simply remove student view data model.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't get your point for duplicate code and separating Student from model. How can I minimize my design. It would be better if you provide an answer with pictures

Comment: Part of the problem is, you're trying to apply a MVC around a MVC, Swing is already a MVC.  To my mind, the `Student` model should provide simple information about the number of students and the ability to get them, it's then up to the view to present in what fashion it needs, albeit a `JTable`, `JList`, so other navigable form. In a "pure" MVC, where the view and model don't know about each other, the controller begins to duplicate functionality, in particular of the model, as the view requests information from the controller, which the controller forwards to the model and back again

Comment: Part of the problem is, you've provided "too" much information. We don't care how the `StudentModel` is created, only that it provides a guaranteed contract to which other aspects of the API can bind to, there is no need for `StudentDatabaseModel` or `StudentViewableDataModel`, as they are implementation details (and in my mind should probably be the same thing)

Comment: @MadProgrammer according to you, StudentDatabaseModel and StudentViewableModel should be same. But is it not good to separate these module because database should be unaware of how information is shown in GUI and vice versa.

As Swing is already MVC, how can I make best use of Swing's MVC in such kind of requirements.

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I don't define the StudentViewableDataModel which is model for JTable or JList, then where should I define Model for JTable, JList or any other view-model component. Should i write these code inside StudentView or somewhere else.

Comment: IMHO - You shouldn't need to, the fact that you have a "model" of the data is the important accept, the fact that the view "happens" to need some kind of additional model to display you model is an implementation detail

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you explain it little more, with the help of diagram if possible

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you have any clue.... If you have an answer.. please provide.....